# Factoring semiprimes whose factors very close to a power of two

Tags: cr.crypto-security, factoring

Are there any factorization algorithms that run well on numbers $N = pq$ where $p,q$ are prime and $p = 2^b - k_p, q = 2^b - k_q$ for very small $k_p,k_q$? What about $p = 2^b + k_p, q = 2^b + k_q$ for very small $k_p,k_q$?

Comment: Can you define precisely what you mean by "very small?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $0 \le k_p < 2^{b/2}$ and $0 \le k_q < 2^{b/2}$, it's easy to factor such numbers.  Consider:

$$N = pq = (2^b-k_p)(2^b-k_q) = 2^{2b} -(k_p+k_q) 2^b + k_p k_q.$$

Under the stated conditions, you can read off the values of $k_p k_q$ and $k_p+k_q$ from the binary representation of $N$, since $0 \le k_p k_q < 2^b$ and $0 \le k_p+k_q < 2^b$.  In particular, $k_p k_q$ can be obtained as $N \bmod 2^b$, and then you can compute $k_p + k_q$ as $(2^{2b} - N + k_p k_q)/2^b$.  Once you know those values, you can solve for $k_p,k_q$ by solving a quadratic equation (you have a system of 2 equations in 2 unknowns; simple algebra can be used to recover the value of the unknowns).  Once $k_p,k_q$ are known, the factorization of $N$ is immediately revealed.

Comment: How do you read off $k_pk_q$ and $k_p + k_q$ with those inequalities? I think you meant to write $k_p + k_q \leq 2^{b/2 + 1}$.

Comment: @RenéG, I've updated my answer to explain how to read them off.  Also if $k_p < 2^{b/2}$ and $k_q < 2^{b/2}$, then it follows that $k_p k_q < 2^b$ and $k_p + k_q < 2^{b/2+1}$, so I think my conditions are correct.  I did not try to optimize to make them the loosest possible conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that when you say that a natural number *n* is "very small," that you mean that for some constant *j*, *n* < *j*.

Given *n* and a promise that its prime factors *p*,*q*, are both within *j* of 2^*b* for some natural number *b* and some natural constant *j*, it's not hard to construct a brute-force algorithm that checks every possible value of *p* and *q* in time polynomial in the size of *n.*

Here's a quick example:

Let *j* = 20, and let *n* = 1018081.

We are guaranteed that the prime factors of *n* are within 20 of a power of 2.

So we need only consider every *m* s.t. *m* +/- 20 <= (2^*b*) for some *b*.

These values include:

```
                           1, 2, 3, 4,   ... ,    21
                        1, 2, 3, 4, 5,   ... ,    22
                  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,   ... ,    24
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ... ,    28
                          ...
     236, ... , 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, ... ,   276
     492, ... , 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, ... ,   532
 1004, ... , 1022, 1023, 1024, 1025, 1026, ..., 1044
```

Because we know that 1024 * 1024 > 1018081, it's clear that we don't need to go beyond 1024 in our list.  This is because we are limited to only two prime factors close to a power of 2.

It ought to be clear that given an integer *n*, the number of values that need to be tested as prime factors of *n* is roughly:  (2 *j* + 1)*(ceil(ln(*n*)/ln(2))).  This means that the "naive" algorithm is good enough in this case.

(Incidentally, the prime factors of 1018081 are 1009 and 1009, so you might want to try a harder example if you decide to code it.)

Comment: What if we're talking about RSA, where $n > 2^{2047}$? Then we could have $j = 2^{100}$ and still be considered very small.

Comment: Also, what about the case where $j = O(n)$?

Comment: I think that if j = O(n), then the naive algorithm ceases to be polynomial time.  This is because "very small" could be as large as the number itself.  On the other hand, if j is constant or O(log n), then I believe that the algorithm will remain polynomial time.  I don't think it's likely you'll break RSA with such a simple approach, though...not that you said that was your goal.

Comment: I know... I was wondering about more sophisticated techniques, say if I know it's within $N/4$ of a power of two.